# 2-D array as a method and returns it as a 1-D array with the maximum element from each row?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, multidimensional-array

so how can i write a method that takes a 2-d array of doubles and returns a 1-D array of doubles with the maximum element from each row?

this is what i have so far, i am aware i might be off a bit

`public static double[][] methodTest(double [][] arr){
    double [] newArr = new double [arr.length];
    int tmp = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++){
       if(arr[row][0] >tmp){
          tmp=arr[row][0];
          }
       }
}`

Pretty much all I have at this point. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it will be this:

```
public static double[] methodTest(double [][] arr){
    double [] newArr = new double [arr.length];

    for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++){
       for(int column = 0; column < arr[row].length;column++){
          if(newArr[row] < arr[row][column]){
             newArr[row]=arr[row][column];
          }
       }
    }
  return newArr;
}
```